# HTML Form: Entering a Line Break in Text Box

Tags: html, forms, textbox, line-breaks

Given a simple text box in the form:

`<input type="text" … >`

Is there any way for the user to inject a line break?

I know that it is possible to fake a form using `curl` or other technology, so I’m not relying on this as a form of protection. It’s more a question on whether a user can do this simply.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, they can't enter a new line in a text input.

They can, however, replace the input with a textarea in their browser's DOM inspector or bypass the form entirely and send an HTTP request with whatever data they want in it.